# need to highlight all SUNDAY

Tags: jquery, telerik-mvc

Is there any way to highlight all SUNDAY of telerik MVC datetime picker controls with a different color...please help.

Answer (score 1):

Define a [SpecialDay](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-collection-editor.html) for one Sunday and set the `Repeatable` property to `Week`. Set the `ItemStyle` to whatever colour you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
.t-content tbody td:first-child {
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

That might do it. (CSS2)